# Get data between curly brackets

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

```
$string = "[john] sometext [rohn] sometext [mohan]";
```

How to get the data between square brackets each in different array.

I have below code

```
preg_match_all("/\((?:[^()]|(?R))+\)/",  $string , $matches);
```

above code works perfect for curly bracket in the way i need, but how to make it work for square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "[john] sometext [rohn] sometext [mohan]";
preg_match_all("/\[([^]]+)\]/",  $string , $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [john]
            [1] => [rohn]
            [2] => [mohan]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => john
            [1] => rohn
            [2] => mohan
        )

)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[          : opening square bracket
(           : start group 1
    [^]]+   : 1 or more any character that is not closing square bracket
)           : end group 1
\]          : closing square racket
```